# Json web tokens and token type Bearer

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, jwt

I'm using the JSON Web Token for Node.js in my API. In every request i have a middleware that validates the token, and return success or false. If success the page will be rendered, if not, the user will be redirect for the login page.. everything ok. My problem is: I'm using ember-simple-auth the the oauth2 authentication, which automatically catch my token and pre-concat with "Bearer". So, when i try to verify the token, i can't, because is not the same. So, how exactly should i verify?

I simple concat token = "Bearer " + access_token ?? Or i am missing some JWT helper?

Thanks.

Comment: So, you're saying ember-simple-auth auto-concatenates your token before you're able to work with it?

Comment: Looks like this is the relevant line in source: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/bc8b3a3c3459c91e501306a79a20d90237cfefb6/addon/authorizers/oauth2-bearer.js#L40

Comment: Yep. I would like to know how can i verify the token in my server if he arrives with the "Bearer".

Answer (score 0):

So, based on comments, you *should* be able to just slice off the string that the ember-simple-auth is auto-concatenating

So:

```
let normalizedToken = oldToken.slice(7)
```

That should give you a token you can use your jwt lib to verify. Does that help? Is there something I'm missing in your question?